# How to import module in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import hashing  power of 16
```

The **hashing  power of 16.py** is the same with my current working directory. The pop-up message is

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I solve this issue?

```
sys.path.append(working directory)
```

This above is not working either.

Comment: Removing the spaces in the name of the Python file you're trying to report is probably the easiest solution. Rename the file to hashing_power_of_16.py and then the import should be `import hashing_power_of_16`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you should remove spaces from filename, because that way it will not work.
If you really want to do this...
Try something like

```
hashing_power_of_16 = __import__("hashing  power of 16")
```

Then you can refer by hashing_power_of_16 to that module.

But using spaces anywhere in naming is bad idea.

Comment: The error  message  is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hashing_power_of_16'` when I tried yours

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your class. hashing power of 16 is not a recomended name. You can rename it something like hashingPowerOfSixteen. After that you can import the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think Python identifiers can't have spaces. So my guess would be it's not working because your file name is having blank spaces. Rename your file(to have a name without spaces) and try again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`import "name of the module"` 
in  case if the module name is lengthy, u can do it as:
`import "name of the module" as "short acronym"`

For example
I have a module named "Mysq" which is nothing but a python file with a function that returns square of the number.

Now if want to use it another program (make sure that you are working in the same directory)
`import Mysq as ps print(ps.sq(3))`

Comment: It's working in the same directory.`import "name of the module" as "short acronym"` is not working

Comment: Error message `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when add quote in the module.

Comment: Do not add quote. `import Myfunc as fn` and then to use the function, give the proper arguments which are passed